# IOS 9.3.3 Couldn't verify app

Tags: ios, settings, verify

I can trust app developers but I can't verify the apps. I need a quick answer please as I'm going away tomorrow. Here is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: I've had that just a week ago and a simple restart worked for me

Answer (score 0):

1.Your network connection is bad，go to Apple developer in safari to check if network is ok.

2.Connect to another wifi or restart iPad